# Android: Save a file to external memory

Tags: android

I have some audio files that my app is downloading, and due to the size of the files it would be nice if I could store them on the user's external storage. However I need them to remain private to my application. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not literally.

You could encrypt them, but then you would have to handle the playing yourself, in order to decrypt them (or play some game like streaming them from a local "server" which decrypts them as it reads).

Realize also that even things within your .apk itself are accessible on most devices (you will need to use care in obfuscating the encryption key), and the contents of your app's private storage folder are readable on the multitude of rooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

One simple suggestion would be to encrypt your file and then store it in external memory. This would keep the data safe and secured. Other application wont be able to access it. To accomplish this you need to convert the file into ByteStream. Then using encryption function encrypt it and store to external memory. Change the extension of your file to some user-defined extension like myExt and store all in certain folder. When you want to use those files in your application, decrypt it and use it. The encryption key will help you to securely protect data.

As per my knowledge this will prevent other application to access your information.